# Binding a mypy type variable for a type alias in the type annotation of an assignment

Tags: python, generics, lambda, mypy, type-alias

```py
from typing import Callable, TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T')

IndicatorFunction = Callable[[T], bool]

# mypy accepts this annotation.
s1: Callable[[T], bool] = lambda x: False

# mypy rejects this annotation, but it's just an alias of the first one.
s2: IndicatorFunction[T] = lambda x: False
```

I am trying to understand how to make mypy consider `T` to be bound in the type annotation for `s2` in the above code snippet. I get the following error:

```
main.py:9: error: Type variable "__main__.T" is unbound
main.py:9: note: (Hint: Use "Generic[T]" or "Protocol[T]" base class to bind "T" inside a class)
main.py:9: note: (Hint: Use "T" in function signature to bind "T" inside a function)
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

The hints helpfully tell me how to bind "T" inside a class and in a function signature, but not how to do so for the type annotation of a lambda expression.

Subquestions:

- How do I bind T in the type annotation of `s2`?
- Why do I not get the same error in the type annotation of `s1`? Since `IndicatorFunction` is an alias for `s1`'s type, I expected both `s1` and `s2` to be accepted by `mypy`.

Comment: I think the fact that `s1` is accepted is a mypy bug. It's okay to define generic type aliases, like `IndicatorFunction`, but you're not supposed to be able to define a variable with unbound type variables in its type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading a lot of PEPs and `mypy`'s issue tracker, I believe I understand what's happening here.

> How do I bind `T` in the type annotation of `s2`?

You can't. There is no syntax defined for it in [PEP 526](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/), which introduced variable annotations.

As far as I can tell, and as implied by mypy's error message, there are only two ways to quantify (bind) a type variable `T` in Python as it stands today:

1. In a class definition, by including either `Generic[T]` or `Protocol[T]` in the inheritance list (or another class that inherits from these two). In other words, `Generic` and `Protocol` are "magical" implicit type variable binders.
2. In a function definition's parameter list, by annotating a parameter with a generic type that contains `T` as a type parameter.

**There is no way to introduce a type variable binding in a [PEP 526](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/) variable annotation.** PEP 526 makes almost no mention of type parameters and generics.

Will Python add a way to bind type variables in variable annotations in the future? It doesn't look like it. [PEP 695](https://peps.python.org/pep-0695/), if accepted, will greatly improve the clarity of type variable binding syntax, but, again, it only treats the above two cases: introducing bindings in either class or function definitions, not in variable annotations.

The next question implied by all this is **why does mypy treat `s1` as valid and implicitly binds `T`?** You can see that mypy does implicitly bind `T` if you try to give it this code:

```py
T = TypeVar('T')

s3: Callable[[T], bool] = lambda x: x + False
```

`mypy` gives these errors:

```
main.py:5: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "Callable[[T], int]", variable has type "Callable[[T], bool]")
main.py:5: error: Unsupported operand types for + ("T" and "bool")
main.py:5: error: Incompatible return value type (got "int", expected "bool")
```

The second one, `Unsupported operand types for + ("T" and "bool")`, shows that `mypy` did bind `T` and infer that `x` is of type `T`.

This appears to be a `mypy` [bug](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/3924). In fact, one of the first posted comments on that bug is a question about `Callable` and aliases of `Callable` being treated inconsistently by `mypy`.

This answers the second question:

> Why do I not get the same error in the type annotation of `s1`? Since `IndicatorFunction` is an alias for `s1`'s type, I expected both `s1` and `s2` to be accepted by `mypy`.

It's the above `mypy` bug.

In contrast, Pyright correctly rejects `s1`, complaining that `Type variable "T" has no meaning in this context` -- in other words, `T` is unbound.